# Mobile Twitter site refuses Webview as client

Tags: ios, twitter, uiwebview

I'm trying to view a users tweets from my app but twitter responses with  a webpage saying:

> **Sorry that page is not supported on mobile at this time**

However if i load the same URL with mobile safari i get a nice webpage with all the tweets.

I'm using this URL: `http://mobile.twitter.com/SOME_USERNAME/tweets`

You can reproduce the error message by visiting the url in safari. If you use safari as developer and you set the user agent to iPhone you'll get the right page.

It seems the webview is sending different headers as User Agent:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone Simulator; CPU iPhone OS 5_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/9B176
```

vs

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone Simulator; CPU iPhone OS 5_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9B176 Safari/7534.48.3
```

Is there anything i could do about this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apperently it **does** work when i remove the `/tweets` part of the URL.

This is not really the answer to my question but it is the best option as long as nobody comes up with a better answer i'll accept this answer.